# Cross validation: what if the validation performances are not significantly different?

Tags: cross-validation

In doing K-fold cross validation, we will get K validation performances for each hyper parameter. What if the two sample mean test shows that the validation performances of different hyper parameters are NOT significantly different? How to decide the optimal hyper parameter then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if there is no difference between two configurations of a model the 'best practice' is to choose the less complex model (i.e. simpler configuration).  In many cases that leaves you with a potentially more easily interpreted model as well as it likely taking less processing power to train or even predict with after the fact. This often referred to as the `law of parsimony` or `Occam's razor` in literature.

Comment: @user112758 if you are happy with the solution please be sure to accept the answer too.